# Rails Relational Database not working how I want

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

## In the console

```
a = Reported.new
```

This works. After tinkering.

```
a.profile  = Profile.first
```

But it's not what I want! I want a.profile to even exist. I want a.reported_by to be a profile! And I want a.reported to be a profile!

Again  what I want is

```
a.reported_by = Profile.last #or any such profile
a.reported = Profile.first #or any such profile
```

## Model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reported, dependent: :destroy
```

## Migration

It doesn't have a reported column, I am not sure about the right way to implement that either.

```
class CreateReporteds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :reporteds do |t|
      t.belongs_to :profile
      t.integer :reported_by
      t.string :reason
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `a.blocked_by` or is it `a.reported_by`? Is it a typo.

Comment: Ahh thanks Kirti! It was a typo! @KirtiThorat but I still have my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your migration seems... off.  I've never seen `t.belongs_to :something` in a migration - shouldn't it be `t.integer :profile_id`?  (I couldn't find documentation supporting the `belongs_to` syntax there).

If you want `Reported#reported_by` to return a `Profile`, then you need a `reported_by_id` integer on it, NOT a `reported_by` integer.  Rails has a convention where you should make your referenced objects (in this case, a `belongs_to :reported_by` relationship) use the `relationship_id` format for it's foreign key.

Then you should have this in your class:

```
class Reported < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reported_by, class_name: "Profile"
end
```

This will make it so it uses `reported_by_id` as the foreign key for a `Profile` object, but return it as `Reported#reported_by`.

Then:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reporteds, foreign_key: 'reported_by_id'
end
```

Should let you do `Profile#reporteds`

And your migration would look like this:

```
class CreateReporteds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :reporteds do |t|
      t.integer :reported_by_id
      t.string :reason
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Okay! So now a.reported_by = Profile.last works. But I want a.reported to bring the profile that was reported! It still doesn't work!

Comment: NVM I got it to work with   belongs_to :reported, class_name: "Profile"

Comment: Ok, make sure you have a `reported_id` on the table too then ;)

Comment: Just for the record: `t.belongs_to` does exist, and so does `t.references`, which will add the correct field, and nothing more. If you use the `schema_plus` gem, it will also correctly create foreign key constraints if you write something like `t.belongs_to :reported, references: :profiles`.